# How To Distinct OrderSymbol() In MQL4

Tags: mql4, mql5

How to distinct `OrderSymbol()` in MQL4?

I have data:

```
Symbol | Type | Size
GBPUSD | Buy  | 1.5
GBPUSD | Buy  | 0.5
EURUSD | Sell | 1
USDJPY | Buy  | 2
```

I want the result:

```
GBPUSD
EURUSD
USDJY
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No direct way. Collect the data and put into array, maybe sort after every insert in order to use binary search (if list is large). Here is an example of parsing current orders.

```
#include<Arrays\ArrayString.mqh>
ArrayString *list = listOfUniqueSymbols();

ArrayString* listOfUniqueSymbols()
   {
    CArrayString *result = new CArrayString();
    for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
       if(!OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS))continue;
       const string symbol=OrderSymbol();
       if(result.Search(symbol)==-1)
         {
          result.Add(symbol);
          result.Sort();
         }
      }
    return result;
   }
```